# How to change the value of a state variable between each iteration of a React component mapping over an array? Trying to display multiple images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, state, fetch-api

In the below component I attempt to get a list of users from the server, and for each user call the getProfileImage() method to call the API using the AuthService.js class to get profile image as a binary octet stream.

I am then trying to store the profile images in the state variable 'images' array to then access the image in the .map() function for each iteration of the recommendedUsers array. However, although the download is occurring successfully for each user with status code = 200, and an octet stream, no images are displayed.

For another component I used a state variable, imgUrl, that I set the value of getProfileImage() to instead of returning the binary data for storing in array and that worked successfully but I am struggling to see how to adapt that to multiple users/images.

Also, there are no errors in console and all server requests are successful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
export const SwipeCard = () => {

    //array of compatible users fetched for a user.
    const [recommendedUsers, setRecommendedUsers] = useState([]);
    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    const userId = AuthService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();


    useEffect(() => {
        getRecommendedUsers().then(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        });
    }, []);

    const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete) => {
        console.log('removing: ' + nameToDelete)
        setLastDirection(direction)
    }

    const outOfFrame = (firstName) => {
        console.log(firstName + ' left the screen!')
    }

    const getRecommendedUsers = async () => {
                const response = await UserService.getRecommendedUsers(userId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    recommendedUsers[i] = data[i];
                    images[i] = getProfileImage(recommendedUsers[i].userId);
                }
                setImages(images);
            });
    }

    const getProfileImage = async (id) => {
        const response = await UserService.downloadProfileImage(id)
            .then(res => res.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                const imgBlob = blob;
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(imgBlob);
                reader.onloadend = () => {
                    const base64data = reader.result;
                    return base64data;
                };
            });
    }


    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div id="loading">
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='tinderCards'>
                {lastDirection ? <h2 className='text'>You swiped {lastDirection}</h2> : <h2 className='text' />}
            {recommendedUsers.map((user) =>
                <TinderCard className='swipeCard' key={user.userId} onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, user.firstName)} onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(user.firstName)}>
                    <div className='card'>
                        <img id='profileImg' src={images[userId]} />
                        <h2>{getFullName(user.firstName, user.lastName)}</h2>
                    </div>
                </TinderCard>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is, you need to `await` the call to `getProfileImage()` so that the call to `setImages` waits for the calls to complete first.

Like this: `images[i] = await getProfileImage(recommendedUsers[i].userId);`